Azure REST API Call - Microsoft.Authorization | Why roleAssignmentApprovals Fails
I have been working on Azure PIM integration project for a while now and have successfully managed to setup REST API calls for "Role Eligibility", "Role Assignments" and "Role Policy Rules". Now when I am trying to setup REST API calls for PIM Assignment Approvals, i find it very strange but I keep getting error. Does anyone know what I am doing different here? Also why the calls that are working using same AuthToken for one endpoint are not working for other?
"error": {
        "code": "GatewayAuthenticationFailed",
        "message": "Gateway authentication failed for 'Microsoft.Authorization'. Diagnostic information: timestamp '20240727T210153Z', tracking id 'XXXXXXX-562b-4468-a067-4cb27d2b1253', request correlation id 'XXXXXXX-562b-4468-a067-4cb27d2b1253'."
    }

As I mentioned earlier the calls for other requests works fine e.g. call to GET roleManagementPolicies works fine using Bearer Auth Token Auth flow.

When I am trying to make a similar call to GET roleAssignmentApprovals, this results in the error I mentioned above.

Few additional details to mention to help understand context:

I am using client_credentials OAuth2.0 authorization flow.
The client_id and client_secret parameters are correctly set and hence all other REST API calls are working fine.
The API permission for Entra ID app have been Granted at tenant level for both Azure Service Management (user_impersonation) & Microsoft Graph (User.Read).
The actual url after replacing variables is something like

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/[SUBSCRIPTIONID]/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignmentApprovals?api-version=2021-01-01-preview'

I have tried to use other grant types as well just to see if that works. Also I did try to use filter={$filter} as per the REST API documentation for Role Assignment Approval.

Instead of using client credential flow, try with authorization code flow

thanks @PratikJadhav. The auth code flow works fine. But this is bit odd since the other API calls work with client crediential flow and just for this call I don't want to follow a different method.
